# How to keep network communication alive while mobile phone is sleeping

Tags: android, network-programming, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I have an app that needs to send packets to a server regularly while working and it is meant to work for about 2 weeks to accomplish a certain task. This app heavily uses both BLE and WiFi for communication purposes. The problem occurs  when mobile device goes to sleep mode and slows down when sending packets. I need a way to keep the service responsible for this job and threads running in it alive and preserve communication speed.

Answer (score 0):

you should use a service

create a service :

```
public class YourService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int id) {
        // do your jobs here
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, id);
        }
    }
```

Create an Application class and start your service:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class));
    }
}
```

see more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

---

**Other solution**

in some devices there is an option to add a specific app to list and prevent terminate that list while device is sleeping , you can try this too

Comment: I am currently implementing this as a service. I just start it from an activity instead of an Application class. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, what i'm saying here might be different for every version of Android, but i will say what to do for my version of Android.

Go and turn off this setting:
Turn off networking devices while phone is off.

OR:
Change this setting:
When to sleep?

Comment: The app developer cannot request the user to do this. The OP requested a way to achieve that as a developer.